# How to decrease spacing between circuit element and label in circuitikz

Tags: labels, circuitikz

Is there an easy way to decrease the spacing between all circuit elements and their labels?

For example, a `\ctikzset{bipole annotation style/.style={...}}` command?

Here is the issue I am facing:
`to[L,l=$u_c$,o-o] ++(-135:1.8)` results in an overlap (below). Manually inserting `\vspace` (i.e. `to[L,l=\vspace{-5pt}$u_c$,o-o]`) has no effect, and using an `\hspace` has undesirable placement.

[image: Overlap issue]

Comment: It will be nice from you if you provide a MWE, which reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You not provide MWE, which reproduce your problem, so we don't know, what is in your circuit code.
- This works:

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{bipoles/inductors/.cd,    % <--- 
            dot x distance=3pt,     % <--- 
            dot y distance=0pt}     % <--- 
\draw(0,0)  to [L, l_=$u_c$, name=lc, mirror,
                   label distance=-3pt, % <--- 
               ] ++ (2,2);
\path (lc.ll dot) node[circ]{};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]